# Компиляция C++ и PHP

Tags: php, компиляция, c++

Господа, ситуация такая:
На сервер отправляется файл с расширением .cpp. Задача движка скомпилировать файл, и, если нет ошибок, выполнить его.
Прошу совета, в какие глубины мне копать, возможно кто-то знает статьи на эту тему, или же что-то еще. Вся информация, любая, даже по мелочи, приветствуется.

Answer (score 5):

Вначале читаем о том, как [запускать программы, используя php и получать вывод](http://dead-krolik.info/2007/06/19/zapusk-vneshnego-prilozheniya-v-php-exec-system-popen-passthru-proc_open).

Дальше, что бы скомпилировать файл, его нужно загрузить (на эту тему есть много статей) или передать как текст post запросом. А потом запустить команду вида `g++ $filename -o $output`. g++ возвращает коды ответа, так что по ним можно узнать, удачна ли компиляция (скорее всего, как любая нормальна linux программа, он будет возвращать 0 в случае успеха).
Но в любом случае, можно проверить, был ли сформирован файл по пути `$output` (его передавали при компиляции).

Собственно, в php можно запускать внешние бинарники и с помощью обратных кавычек.

А запуск... а он ничем не отличается от компиляции. Таким же образом все запускается. Путь к запускаемому файлу известен.

Comment: про команду можно поподробней? я потерялся с фразы "вида g++ $filename -o $output. g++ "

Comment: `g++` - это компилятор для языка с++, который легко устанавливается на практически любой линукс дистрибутив. (да, такое интересное имя с двумя плюсами).

Настоятельно рекомендую в консоли скопмилировать хотя бы примитивный helloworld. Иначе, вся дальнейшая работа будет бессмысленной.


Присмотритесь внимательно, команда немного короче, чем Вам показалось.

    g++ $filename -o $output

    $filename - это имя файла с путем, который нужно скомпилировать (исходник).
    $output - это путь + имя файла, куда компилятор разместит готовый бинарник (если у него это получится).

Answer (score 4):

Сам по себе процесс компиляции достаточно прост: нужно лишь запустить из командной строки компилятор (например, GCC; само собой, он должен быть установлен на сервере) и передать ему нужный файл. Получить вывод компилятора, проверить его на предмет сообщений об ошибках и запустить полученный после компиляции файл также не представляет труда. Всё вышеописанное легко провернуть с помощью функции [`system()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.system.php). Зато возникает серьёзная проблема - безопасность. Ничто не мешает пользователю написать код, удаляющий важные файлы на сервере. Поэтому нужно организовать "[песочницу](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_(%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C))", в которой будет запускаться приложение. Либо запускать программу в виртуалке, которую не жалко испортить и котроую легко поднять заново в автомтическом режиме, либо запускать программу от имени пользователя с максимально урезанными правами.

Comment: "Всё вышеописанное легко провернуть с помощью функции system()". А можно хотя бы статейку...или просто пояснить-как? Вот предположим у меня компилятор - MinGW (простой, удобный, бесплатный) или какой-нить еще, не суть, так вот как ему сказать, что запусти-ка мне этот файл, а результат сюда пожалуйста.?

Comment: Чтиайте документацию вашего компилятора, там описан процесс запуска его из командной строки. Ваша задача сформировать команду для запуска компилятора, передать её в функцию `system` и сохранить возвращённое ей значение (вывод вашего компилятора). В выводе можно найти сообщения об ошибках или успешной компиляции.