# Компилляция прокта C++ из под РНР

Tags: php, c++

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся со следующей задачей - необходимо компиллировать проект, написанный на C++ из под PHP.

Погуглил, наткнулся вот на это: 
[Компиляция C++ и PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/244018/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-c-%D0%B8-php)

Т.е, как я понял, всего то и стоит, что вызвать G++ через `system()` или `exec()` , и выйдет примерно следующее:

```
$out = exec(g++ $proj -o $o);
```

Но вот хотелось бы следующее прояснить - насколько данный подход может быть опасен? Тем более, что код проекта практически полностью статичен и меняется перед компилляцией минимум информации.

Интересно мнение экспертов, в общем.

Comment: Если используется слово *проект*, то адекватней вызывать `make`.

Comment: Хм. А в каком смысле «опасен»? Расскажите свою модель угроз. У вас код поставляет потенциально злонамеренный пользователь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, надо обезопасить переменные `#proj` и `$o` это в любом случае, хотя и linux не даст доступ, если `$proj = /etc/myproj`, а сам код программы берет файл passwd, например, вот это небезопасно, вы ходите по очень тонкому льду, тут много уязвимостей. И в первую очередь настройте права доступа к файлам, затем закройте любую возможность эти права поменять.

Comment: А еще для python есть такая вешь, как virtualenv, может, и для пхп найдете, ее суть в том, что она сама создает в какой-либо папке свое окружение, настройки которого не будут зависеть от системных и меняться отдельно, это, конечно, больше используется для менеджмента проектов, но может вам понадобится и в таком ключе.